# Where to add payload URL for Twitter webhook?

Tags: twitter, webhooks, twitterapi-python

Github has a webhooks tab in the settings of a repository and it has a submission for a payload URL. I looked all over the developer site for Twitter but I can't really find anything. I'm still really new to how all of this works.

Answer (score 0):

For Twitter, you need to add your webhook URLs programmatically via the API. The documentation is [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/api-reference/aaa-premium#post-account-activity-all-env-name-webhooks). You'll need to send an authenticated HTTP POST request to `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/[YOUR_ENV_NAME]/webhooks.json` with the URL specified in the URL parameter.

If you would like something that does more of the work for you - although this is in JavaScript, not Python - you can take a look at [this tutorial using autohook](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/twitter-account-activity-tutorial-autohook).